# require cdn libraries in browserify without bundling it in the final js file

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, browserify

If I have a library that is being pulled down from cdn and wouldn't like it to be part of the final js file but be able to require it using browserify, how would I solve it?

Here is how I currently solve it using `alias` and a shim file.

```
browserify: {
    options: {
        debug: true,
        transform: [ 'reactify' ],
        alias: [
            'client/shims/jquery.js:jquery'
        ]
    },
    app: {
        src:  'client/app.js',
        dest: 'public/app.js'
    }
}
```

here is the shim file `client/shims/jquery.js` which I alias to `jquery` so I can use `require('jquery')` instead of the full path.

```
module.exports = $;
```

Is there a shortcut in grunt-browserify to support this scenario? I would like to know if it is possible to define it in Gruntfile.js without creating the shim file.

Adding `external: [ 'jquery' ]` seems to totally ignore it and doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like  I have a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20915307/creating-a-bundle-supporting-browserify-and-jquery-script-tag-loading - I am currently handling this outside browserify and just explicitly passing jQuery to the library through a config. https://github.com/miohtama/bitcoinaddress.js/blob/master/demo.js#L77 However my solution is not ideal.

Comment: Wanted to ask the same question. Any news on this one?

Answer (score 27):

With [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim)  you can add this in your package.json file:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },

  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery": "global:$"
  }
```

Then jquery will be available in your modules via `require('jquery')`

Comment: What about third-party modules that require jquery?  It seems as though browserify-shim isn't replacing those requires with globals, anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you load jQuery before the Browserify bundle on the page, `$` will be available as a global.