# Creating a bundle supporting browserify and jQuery <script> tag loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, browserify

I am working on [a JavaScript library (bitcoin-prices.js)](https://github.com/miohtama/bitcoin-prices) which I'd like to maintain using browserify. The library depends on jQuery. I would not like to force the library users move to browserify, but retain "drop one file + script tag" integration for those who have not drank the latest koolaid from JavaScript community.

My question is how to create a bundle.js with browserify, so that

- browserify-enabled users can install the package from NPM, having proper jQuery dependency
- Traditional users can as still use `<script>` tag drop in bundle, loading their jQuery wherever they want to with another `<script>` and the code still works fine

I guess some kind of boilerplate code is needed around `$ = require('jquery.js')`?

Answer (score 4):

The convention is to do like this (without the .js):

```
var $ = require('jquery')
```

If you are using grunt-browserify (https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify),

Compile your library in this way:

```
  your_task:{
    src:'{{your library's js file}}',
    dest:'{{your library's browserified file}}',
    options: {
      external: ["jquery"]
    }
  },
```

At the home page, the sequence will then be like this:

```
<header>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{your library's browserified file}}"></script>
</header>
```

Hope this helps